# Translation from plain English to a set of instruction

Tags: semantics, user-interaction, semantic-analysis, language-translation

I have a set of instructions, for example Linux's "ls", "grep", "cd", etc.

I want the user to be able to execute this commands without knowing the exact names and parameters but rather with something similar to their meaning in plain English, e.g. "show me all folders", "filter all files by name" , "go to directory". Or in other words: the user input is "Show me all files and then show me all that contains 'foo' " to be translated to "ls | grep foo"

I understand that I will need some kind of meta-information about each instruction and do some kind of evaluation how close is the user query term to each instruction. Something like:

```
  <instruction>
      <command>ls</command>
      <semantic>lists all files</semantic>
      <plainEnglish>List all the files in this directory</plainEnglish>
      <synonyms>
          <synonym>Show all files</synonym>
          ...etc
      </synonyms>
  </instruction>
```

So which is the important information and how to do this evaluation?

Any general guidelines how I can translate the user's input to a specific instruction from my set? (This sounds like quite a challenge to me)